# how to get fileds which matches a string in text file using php

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi i have a text file

```
=====1st record
name:sam
designation:developer
area:usa

=====2nd record
name:john
designation:tester
area:canada
```

like this i have some records(not in same order), my requirement is to extract all "designation" fields with values, how to write a batch file to extract this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need Windows cms shell script or php code?

Comment: i need windows cms shell script only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<inputfile>outputfile findstr /i "designation"
type outputfile
```

Comment: thanks its working fine simply with this command findstr "designation" sample.txt, but i want to display all three fileds based on designation if designation==developer, can u please suggest me

Comment: can you use `sed` for Windows [GNU Win](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) ?